# How to use keras.preprocessing.ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe() method when the column contains target labels in form of vectors? (Keras)

Tags: python, dataframe, keras, conv-neural-network, image-preprocessing

I am training a CNN model. I am using a dataframe which contains **one column for the image path**. The other columns(bbox, category,attributes) contains **target labels stored as encoded list**. The snippet of the dataframe is given here:
[The dataframe used for training](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPZfW.png)

Now the `keras.preprocessing.ImageDatagenerator.flow_from_dataframe` method in keras asks for the argument`class_mode`. No class mode seem to work.

Can anyone guide me on what should be done to read target labels directly in form of vector?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are interested in image-classification here, right?

Comment: Yes @AdityaMishra . I am working on the DeepFashion Dataset. The 'category' column is a one hot vector representation of the category it belongs to.

Comment: Check the answer I've provided below

Answer (score 1):

Sample Dataframe -

```
     images     labels                bbox
0  img1.jpg  [0, 0, 1]  [72, 79, 232, 273]
1  img2.jpg  [1, 0, 0]  [67, 59, 155, 161]
2  img3.jpg  [0, 1, 0]  [51, 62, 167, 182]
```

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image

generator = image.ImageDataGenerator()
generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df, x_col="images", y_col="labels")
```

Outputs an iterator object which u can iterate over or pass to your model -

```
Found 3 validated image filenames belonging to 2 classes.
<keras_preprocessing.image.dataframe_iterator.DataFrameIterator at 0x13b379898>
```

Comment: In this case, shouldn't the image belong to **3 different classes**? I want it to be divided into 3 classes (as per your sample dataframe). In my data the "category" column is the one hot representation of the category of fashion apparel in image. There are total 50 categories and hence the one hot labels are of shape [1,50]

Comment: How is it different than the sample dataframe I created? The solution would work even if it's just 3, 10 or 20 categories

Comment: I want something like: ```Found XYZ validated image filenames belonging to 50 classes```.